# accessing image files from a separated assembly

Tags: wpf, ribbon, bitmapimage

I have several image files I want to share between projects(common icons) I have them in an assembly that would be in every solution I create...I have the files in a folder called Icon and I have the build as content copy always. I have verified that a folder is created with these icons...however my other assemblies are not able to find them...

```
<r:RibbonGroup Header="Users">
    <r:RibbonButton >
       <r:RibbonButton.LargeImageSource>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="..\Icons\UserIcon.png" />
       </r:RibbonButton.LargeImageSource>
    </r:RibbonButton>
</r:RibbonGroup>
```

i have tried formatting the uri several ways...but it never succeeds. If the icons are in the actual assembly though they work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an absolute Uri. Build action must be set to Resource for UserIcon.png

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/NameOfImageAssembly;component/Icons/UserIcon.png"/>
```

Relative Uri should also work

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="/NameOfImageAssembly;component/Icons/UserIcon.png"/>
```

Comment: For some reason, in my case the absolute URI throws a uri format exception, whereas relative works OK