# wpf: how to use image with relative path while image isn't resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml file going to be dynamic loaded:

```
XamlReader.load("a.xaml")
```

It contains a `BitmapImage` resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <BitmapImage x:Key = "some" UriSource = "someFile.png" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`someFile.png` is under the path the same with `a.xaml`, but it's not a`Resource`. Then when load VS hints:

> Can't locate file someFile.png.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing image files from a separated assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475124/accessing-image-files-from-a-separated-assembly)

Comment: Try Drag and Drop that image file from solution explorer.

Comment: The XamlReader doesn't check whether the Uri is valid. How and when you are you using the BitmapImage?